# HyperLinkField in Gridview not showing link on column's items

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, gridview

I have a question today about the usage of HyperLinkField in a GridView.  I have searched nearly everything, but nothing I try is working.  I am running and ORACLE database and all of the fields below are string type EXCEPT for RECORD_DATE and RECORD_TIME.  They are of type 'DATE'.

This is what I have:

```
 <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="MODEL_NUMBER" DataTextField="MODEL_NUMBER" SortExpression="MODEL_NUMBER" DataNavigateUrlFields="MODEL_NUMBER, SERIAL_NUMBER, DEFECT_CODE, RECORD_DATE, RECORD_TIME"
                DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/AllAudits.aspx?Model={0}&Serial={1}&Defect={2}&RecordDate={3}&RecordTime={4}" />
```

Visual Studio has no complaints with the string, and the page loads fine and everything, but it isn't showing a link for the column labeled "MODEL_NUMBER" like it should be.

I tried:

```
 NavigateUrl="~/AllAudits.aspx"
```

And that created a link, but I don't think I have the ability to pass parameters through this.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction on this?

Comment: Oooh, I think I might need to do a RowDataBound() event handler for the GridView, although, I'm not sure exactly how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may have something to do with how you are passing in the date types. [This thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1045143.aspx/1) seems to resolve the problem you are having.

Comment: Yeah, it is the date types.  I removed them from the URL to test it, and they are being passed flawlessly now.  How would I go about changing them before passing them?

Comment: Yeah, it is definitely the date and time strings.  How would I go about modifying my format string to do this?

Comment: [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) shows the different formats you can use. For example for a short date string you will have `{0:d}` instead of just `{0}`.

Comment: I decided to not use the date events (they weren't part of the primary keys for these records).  But thanks a lot, this information will definitely benefit me in the future!  :)